# How to track Twilio sms message relationships in my application

Tags: twilio, webhooks

I am dev'ing a project where someone creates an event, and a group of people get an sms message inviting them. I want the recipient to be able to rsvp via sms. So if they respond "yes" I want to know what event_id they are responding to0.

I am passing a:

```
"statusCallback" => "https://cbd5-67-183-175-137.ngrok.io/receive-note/12345"
```

(not a real event id, just testing)

I don't care about the message status at this point, just if a response comes in. What parameter can I pass to the create message call that will allow me to dynamically track what event this invite was for?  Is it a webhook or some kind of grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no concept of replying to a specific message in SMS, messages are just chronological.

The [statusCallback URL for an SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/sms-webhooks#type-2-status-callbacks) will only report on the status of the message you are sending to the end user, from queuing the message to be sent all the way through to delivery.

When a user sends an SMS to your Twilio number it triggers the [incoming message webhook](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/sms-webhooks#type-1-incoming-message).

The incoming message webhook has no connection to an outbound message at all. So you will have to work out what message you think the user is replying to. A simple way to do this is to assume that they are replying to the last message you sent to them or the last event invite.

You are probably already considering what might happen if a user is sent invites to more than one event at the same time. How can you distinguish which event they are replying about. You have a couple of options here.

You can only ever send one SMS about an invite at a time, up until a timeout of sorts. That way, when a user replies you can always assume it's about the latest message.

Or, you can send invite message from different Twilio numbers. If you then store the outbound number with the invite you can look up replies based on the user's number and the number they replied to and calculate which invite they are responding to. To achieve this, you need more than one Twilio number, but you should only need as many numbers as the maximum estimated number of events a user might be invited to at one time.

Finally, you could ask the user to include an event ID or similar in their reply which you can then parse out, but this is likely to be a difficult ask of users.

Comment: What about when someone "likes" an SMS message? Is that possible to track with Twilio?

Comment: "Likes" are not a feature of SMS really. I just tested with my iPhone and an SMS from a Twilio number and if you "like" a message from a Twilio number then the Twilio number receives a message saying "Liked 'original message content'". So, while you do get the original message content in the "Like" message, there is nothing else that ties the "Like" to a message ID of any sort.

Answer (score -1):

This exists in SendGrid and is very useful. I don't understand how it's not implemented in Twilio.

Comment: Because unlike SMS, replies are implemented in emails, via headers and citations.